# как сделать проверку на букву

Tags: python

тоесть if input == и любая буква:
то и выболняется команда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используем метод `isalpha()`, который проверяет, состоит ли строка только из букв, и `len()`, чтобы убедиться, что введена именно 1 буква (считаем длину строки).

```
user_input = input()
if len(user_input) == 1 and user_input.isalpha():
    print('Введена буква', user_input)
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

Если основная задача - проверить условие ввода пользователя, используя команду `if`, то предлагаю свой вариант:

```
letter = input('Gimme letter: ')

if letter.isalpha():
    print(f'This is a letter -> {letter}')
```

Метод `isalpha()` проверяет строку и возвращает значение `True`, если она состоит только из буквенных символов (aA-zZ, аА-яЯ).

Также возможно использовать регулярные выражения - regex. Как пользоваться очень понятно объяснено на [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp).

Удачи в начинаниях!

Comment: спасибо большое! Вы лучший!!!